# PHP date("t", mktime(0,0,0,1,$x,2014)); always returns 31, not >31 for $x=2,4,6 etc. should return last of month

Tags: php, date

```
for ($x=1;$x<=12;$x++) {
    echo(date("t", mktime(0,0,0,1,$x,2014)));
}
```

This returns 31 for each $x, what am i doing wrong? It should return the numbers of days in a month $x, so it should be 28 for $x=2, 30 for $x=4 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to mktime are the american style month, day, year.

```
echo(date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,2014)));
```

You are currently asking for the `$x`th day of January.

Comment: Ahhh so easy, I can't believe it.

Answer (score 2):

You have the day and month parameters swapped:

> int mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int $second = date("s") [, int $month = date("n") [, int $day = date("j") [, int $year = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )

```
for ($x=1;$x<=12;$x++) {
    echo(date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,2014)));
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/179059)

Comment: Demos are real hard to beat; sweetens the pot *as it were*.

Comment: Apparently they *can* be beaten, though. :O

Comment: Yeah, but the styling's pretty cool. `href`'s are ok, but that `Demo` button, that got me ;)

Comment: Cool hair btw ;) I got me a goatie too.

Comment: Lol. I guess you found me? It's just for the summer but I'm having a lot of fun with it. :)

Comment: Gawd... it's been a while lol. Wait a sec, I'll say "hello" ;) You'll know it's me. Look in your "other" ;)